# Scaffold creates too many files for me. What should I do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm new in the world of Ruby on Rails. I have some problems to solve before start to build a store-like web application.
I'm following instructions written in the book "Agile Web Development with Rails" so I decided to use sqlite too...

...but I have already represented the scenario via ER Diagrams and now I don't know how to bring it on rails.

In the early chapters of the book, it uses the scaffold command to create the table "Product". But this command creates model, view, controller and test for every table I want to represent.

Is it the right way to proceed? Or is there a way to build all my tables before I start to create mvc I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the Guides to Ruby On Rails:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

It's generally easier to understand (in my opinion) than the Agile book.

The easiest way to create your tables is by using Rails migrations.

The easiest way to create migrations with the related models, views, and controllers is:

```
rails generate scaffold Product
```

That command will print what it's doing. Take a look in those files.

If you have many tables, yes the typical way is to generate many scaffolds, for example:

```
rails generate scaffold User
rails generate scaffold Product
rails generate scaffold Company
rails generate scaffold Invoice
...
```

In your comment you ask about a type_of_product table. For tables like these, yes it's fine to skip the scaffold (for example because you don't need a controller) and instead just generate a migration:

```
rails generate migration TypeOfProduct
```

Heads up that Rails does odd things with the word "type". When I did a table like that, I found it easier to start with the main word then use the word "kind" like this:

```
rails generate migration ProductKind
```

Comment: Well, yes. In most cases - unless you want to create the tables in migrations: you can create 20 tables in a single migration, but this is _not a Rails way_.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **YES**, this is the right way.

Longer answer: Usually you want to design a model, then design the next one, so *usually* this is the right way. If you create a table without a model, there is no value in pure existence of a table.

If you want to create only tables, without a model, you may create migration. Just use `./script/rails generate migration CreateSomeTable`.

In any case you may just ignore the created files which you do not need right now. Just let them stay where they are, and focus on all the tables (migrations) if you wish so.

Comment: when i generate a scaffold for tables like "type_of_product" rails generates all the mvc for show "type_of_product" create new "type_of_products" and so on but i don't need it

Comment: Scaffold creates a table, a model, and a controller with standard views. If you do not need these, do not use scaffold. Create `model` or `migration`.

Comment: so if i generate the model it creates the table avoiding the creation of view and controller right?

Answer (score 2):

Scaffolding gives you a great starting point for working with a resource, such as a user, post, article, etc. It generates models, views and controllers and then you can focus on modifying it to fit your needs.

Your entity relationship diagram gives you a great roadmap for building your system. You shouldn't be worrying about big banging 20 tables into the app at once. You should, instead, build them out one and a time (through scaffolding or the other rails generators for models and migrations) working on them until they are right, then building out the other tables and relationships one at a time.

Work small and you'll be incredibly productive. Work large and you'll spend a lot of wasted time trying to figure out where you went wrong in a single giant operation.

Comment: +1 This is a good advice. I was trying to say the same, but it was you who said it clearly. :-)